# Concerned about methods of backlogging network messages in the event of a LAN outage

Tags: c#, multithreading, overhead

I'm working in a Windows 7 Embedded environment, with very few resources left after everything is loaded in.

There are about 8 different message types that the clients (Win 7 Embedded) can send to the server, but only 2 of them are of high importance (the must be sent after any period of network outage). The other 6 messages I have set to retry for about 30 seconds if there is a send failure.

My concern is how I will be holding these messages in memory. My two ideas so far are:

1) having the threads the messages are trying to send on sleep until network connectivity is regained (this could lead to a lot of sleeping threads if, say, the network was out for several days).

2) writing messages that were unable to send to a file, then flushing the file and sending each message when connectivity is regained.

What I'm wondering is if method 1 would cause too much overhead, if say 50 threads were in a 'Sleep' state?

If so, should I go with option 2?

Perhaps there's another, more clever option, I haven't considered yet also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2 of them are of high importance

If this is the case, you should probably not rely on leaving the messages in memory, especially with the consideration

> if, say, the network was out for several days

If there is a power loss or other restart/failure, the messages would be lost if in RAM.

I suggest serializing the messages to a persistent store (e.g. disk).  When you detect that network connectivity is restored, check for serialized messages and send them then.  Make sure the message is transmitted before deleting from disk (just in case the network goes down again after you first detected it up, but before you send the message).

Comment: Ah, right, I don't know why I wasn't thinking of an event in which the device itself loses power. Writing to a file it is! Thanks.